# Dualboot kodi and console emulator on rpi 4

Tags: boot, pi-4, emulation

Can I have a dual boot on **Raspberry Pi 4B 4G** with Kodi (Libreelec) and some console emulation to play games?
How the dualboot behaves?
Do I need to have full OS to handle it?

NOTE: I know how dual boot behaves on pc (win + linux) - is it same? I already have a Kodi on rpi3, and I did not try any console emulation yet, but I would like to be able to play some simple games like Crash Bandicoot. Sources to setup rpi4 are welcommed in answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of PINN that will let you pick any one of a multitude of operating systems to multi-boot on your RPi.

You should be able to fit LibreElec, OSMC, Retropie and Raspbian on a 32GB or 64GB SDcard.

https://github.com/procount/pinn

Comment: thank you, i will look at the project, looks good